# Need a script that generates files from words within a single text files

Tags: text-processing, shell-script

I have the following scenario and my lack of linux knowledge doesn't help a lot.

I have a text file that contains YML values, in the following matters:

```
coolregion:
  min: {z: -99613.0, y: 45.0, x: -99805.0}
  flags: {vehicle-place: allow}
  max: {z: 100387.0, y: 127.0, x: 100195.0}
  priority: 0
  type: cuboid
  owners:
    groups: [jacob, eithan, michael]
  members:
    groups: [jack, noah]
niceregion:
      min: {z: 544.0, y: 6.0, x: 184.0}
  flags: {}
  max: {z: 556.0, y: 13.0, x: 197.0}
  priority: 0
  type: cuboid
  owners:
    groups: [noah]
  members:
    groups: [logan, lucas, jack]
```

I want to generate files for each name with the regions that he belongs to.

For example `noah.txt` will contain `coolregion, niceregion` while `jacob.txt` will contain `coolregion` only.

I know regex pretty well so I'd be also pleased if you only point me to the right direction (i.e. a script that only needs the regex to complete).

If it matters, my linux version is "Debian GNU/Linux 5.0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an awk solution. I don't know YML, so you may need to fiddle with the regexps (e.g. can the region marker be indented?). Note that the `print data >filename` construct creates or truncates the file the first time it's reached for a given file name, and then appends to the file.

```
<input.yml awk '
/^[^ :]+: *$/ {sub(/: *$/,""); region=$0}     # start of region
/^ *groups:/ {                                # owner or member list
    sub(/^[^:]*: *\[/, ""); sub(/\].*/, "");  # extract bracketed names
    split($0, names, / *, */);                # split comma-separated list
    for (n in names)                          # iterate over names
        print region >names[n] ".txt";        # write or append to name file
}'
```

---

Don't take it too seriously, but here's a sed and shell solution.

```
<input.yml sed -n -e '/^[^ ]/ h' \
                  -e '/^ \+groups:/ {' \
                    -e 'G' \
                    -e 's/^[^:]*: *\[\(.*\)\]\n\(.*\):/\2,\1/' \
                    -e 's/, \+/,/g' \
                    -e 'p' -e '}' | (
  IFS=,; set -f
  while read -r region names; do
    for name in $names; do
      echo "$region" >>"$name.txt"
    done
  done
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works lovely. The regions are indeed indent so I added 2 spaces before the `[^ :]+:` to make it work. YML is all about the right number of spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

A 'perl' solution:

Script:

```
use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                       
use strict;                                                                                                                                                                         

die "Usage: perl $0 file\n" unless @ARGV == 1;                                                                                                                                      

my (%hash, $region);                                                                                                                                                                

open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die "Cannot open file $ARGV[0]: $!\n";                                                                                                                

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {                                                                                                                                                        

        ## Get region, characters until first ':' without spaces at the beginning.                                                                                                  
        $region = $1 if $line =~ /^([^:\s]+)/;                                                                                                                                      

        ## Get names with a regex and save them as keys of a hash, values will be                                                                                                   
        ## regions.                                                                                                                                                                 
        if ( $line =~ /^\s*(?i:groups):\s*\[([^\]]*)\]\s*$/ ) {                                                                                                                     
                my @names = split /,\s*/, $1;                                                                                                                                       
                for my $name ( @names ) {                                                                                                                                           
                        push @{ $hash{ $name } }, $region;                                                                                                                          
                }                                                                                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                   

## Read names (keys of the hash), open a file for each one and write regions on it.                                                                                                 
for my $name ( sort keys %hash ) {                                                                                                                                                  
        my $outfile = $name . ".txt";                                                                                                                                               
        open my $ofh, ">", $outfile or do { warn "Cannot open $outfile: $!\n"; next };                                                                                              
        print $ofh join( ", ", @{ $hash{ $name } } ), "\n";                                                                                                                         
        close $ofh or warn "Cannot close $outfile\n";                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                   

close $fh or warn "Cannot close $ARGV[0]\n";
```

Execution:

```
$ perl script.pl infile
```

Comment: If you're using Perl, you can fairly easily use an actual YAML parser, which would add some robustness.